# Why is my Rotation Matrix not working when i change the gamma angle?

Tags: python, numpy

im currently working on some molecular simulations, but cant figure out why one part of my rotation matrix is nor working properly. 
Here my code:

```
import numpy as np
import math as math

alpha   = 0
beta    = 0
gamma   = 0

R_x_a = np.array([[1, 0, 0],[0, np.cos(alpha), -np.sin(alpha)],[0, np.sin(alpha), np.cos(alpha)]])
R_y_b = np.array([[np.cos(beta), 0, np.sin(beta)], [0, 1, 0], [-np.sin(beta), 0, np.cos(beta)]])
R_z_g = np.array([[np.cos(gamma), -np.sin(gamma), 0],[np.sin(gamma), np.cos(gamma), 0],[0, 0, 1]])


#Rot_matrix = np.dot(R_x_a, R_y_b, R_z_g)

print(R_x_a)
print(R_y_b)
print(R_z_g)
```

Whenever i try this code and change the alpha value, the first x-rotation matrix is working properly, but it influences the z-rotation matrix in some way.
Whenever i change the gamma value it changes it in some curious way and i dont know how to fix this problem.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I think you need to understand some things about basic rotations. Like why they don't commute. It's actually gamma that changes the others, alpha being the innocent bystander, at least in the order that you have. Have you considered using quaternions?

Comment: Read through the docs of [`scipy.spatial.transform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.transform.html#module-scipy.spatial.transform) for some ideas how to do this simpler

Answer (score 0):

You did not show any code of how you are applying these rotations. Possibly make sure you are using

```
np.matmul(rotation, vector)
```

otherwise your code seemed to work for me when I ran it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i dont get it.
I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import math as math
pi = np.pi


steps = [0, pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2, 2*pi]
def rotation_matrix(alpha, beta, gamma):
    global R_x_a
    global R_y_b
    global R_z_g
    R_x_a = np.array([[1, 0, 0],[0, np.cos(alpha), -np.sin(alpha)],[0, np.sin(alpha), np.cos(alpha)]])

    R_y_b = np.array([[np.cos(beta), 0, np.sin(beta)], [0, 1, 0], [-np.sin(beta), 0, np.cos(beta)]])

    R_z_g = np.array([[np.cos(gamma), -np.sin(gamma), 0],[np.sin(gamma), np.cos(gamma), 0],[0, 0, 1]])

    Rot_matrix = np.matmul(R_z_g, R_y_b, R_x_a)



for i in steps:
    print(i)
    rotation_matrix(i, 0, 0)
    print(R_x_a[2,2], "\n")
```

I did this to try whether my code is doing something or not.
The list is just to iterate some fractions of pi.
Still, the code is doing nothing.

Output:

```
0
1.0 

1.5707963267948966
1.0 

3.141592653589793
1.0 

4.71238898038469
1.0 

6.283185307179586
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your actual code for the rotations is correct just your use of global variables resets the R_x_a to the first result of calculating it after the function is run each time try this instead.

```
import numpy as np
pi = np.pi


steps = [0, pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2, 2*pi]
def rotation_matrix(alpha):
    return np.array([[1, 0, 0],[0, np.cos(alpha), -np.sin(alpha)],[0, np.sin(alpha), np.cos(alpha)]])


for i in steps:
    print(i)
    R_x_a = rotation_matrix(i)
    print(R_x_a[2,2], "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you, at least this works now, but how can i get this array available outside the function with the given values after calling the function itself?

Comment: @Winkelpromille if you want to use any of the things generated in a function you can just return it and then store it in a variable if instead you want your function to instead be a method then your could create a rotation class with a similar class method.